# C# HttpClient request to invalid address returns "OK" 200 code. Why?

Tags: c#, httprequest, nunit, dotnet-httpclient

I have a weird problem. Im trying to write very simple c# nunit-based http request tests.
But when Im sending GET requests to non-existing endpoints I still get 200 "OK" code? Requests sent by Postman are working fine and give 404 when expected. "Users" endpoint exist and returns empty json (for now), Users2 emdpoint does not exist.

Sorry for censoring site address, but I dont think it's relevant here.

What do I do wrong here?

[image]

[image]

```
namespace TestProject1
{
   [TestFixture("OK", "Users2")]
   [TestFixture("OK", "Users")]
   public class Tests
   {
    public string Code { get; set;}

    public string Url = "https://examplewebsite.net";

    public Tests(string code) 
    {
        this.Code = code;
    }

    public Tests(string code, string endpoint)
        : this(code)
    {
        Url = string.Format("{0}/{1}",
            Url,
            endpoint);       
    }

    public async static Task<string> HttpGetAsync(string url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(url);
        string content = null;

        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(url)
        };

        var response = await client.GetAsync("");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(content);

        return response.StatusCode.ToString();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => HttpGetAsync(Url));
        task.Wait();
        string responseCode = task.Result;
        Assert.AreEqual(Code, responseCode);
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Because the link isn't invalid according to the server. 200 was returned by the remote server, not HttpClient. What's the actual link and what does the *server* do? Post code and links as *text*, not images

Comment: This isn't a problem with the HttpClient, it is just returning what the webserver is sending back. Examine the request with a tool like Curl to see the response from webserver, it will most likely also be a 200 response.

Comment: You've hidden the URL and there's no server code. It's impossible to guess why *the server* returned 200, or what the difference in the requests was. The test code is certainly unusual - why `var task = Task.Run(() => HttpGetAsync(Url));` instead of `await HttpGetAsync(Url);` ? Or `var string=await client.GetStringAsync(url);` and let the test fail if an error is returned?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Im sorry for this oddity, Im not a C# developer by any stretch of imagination. I just spotted that without this Wait(), code returns to [Test] right after

var response = await client.GetAsync("");

during debugging and rest of the code is unreachable? Not sure how it works exactly with async functions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I sent requests via Postman and they work properly. Request to invalid endpoint returns 404. I dont understand why it returns 200 in C#.

Comment: Because a different request was made. Even `client.GetAsync("")` is unusual - why not `client.GetAsync(myAbsoluteUrl)`? Is the base URL a *valid* one perhaps? You should get comfortable with both async methods and using HttpClient properly, otherwise you aren't testing the server but the test code

Comment: Is the code here the same as your test code (besides the value of Url field)? Because I notice this line `Console.WriteLine(url);` is absent in your screenshot.

Comment: You can rewrite `Test1` as `public async Task Test1(){ var client=new HttpClient(); var text=await client.GetStringAsync(URL);}`. If the server returns 404 `GetStringAsync` will throw an exception. There's no need for an explicit base address

Comment: I suggest to reduce your code to a minimal example like a console app that only does the HTTP request and prints the response code. The test code is a bit confusing and I'm not 100% convinced it's doing the same request your are doing with Postman.

Comment: But even then the server might very well decide to return different things based on `User-Agent`. So what's the server? A frontend app of yours?

Comment: @shingo Yes because I commented that part out to hide Url as it's private project and I dont think I should show it here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried that but result is the same. I still get 200 response code on invalid endpoint

Comment: `I dont think I should show it here.` then there's no way to help you. The URL and the actual server code are causing the problem - assuming there is one. If the URL looks like `http://localhost:333/User?ID=/User2`, it's a perfectly valid GET request to UserController with an ID parameter value of `/User2`. If it's `http://localhost:333/User#/User2` it's still a valid call to UserController without any parameters and a fragment part. Fragments aren't part of a page's URL so won't cause any 404. They're used to link to an anchor *inside* the page.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I solved it. It really turned out the the URL was bad. I was expecting endpoints to be base url + endpoint, while base url for the webpage was different than for endpoints. Case closed. Thank you for your help and patience :)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, I was expecting endpoints to be base url + endpoint, while base url for the webpage was different than for endpoints.